# Отмена класса :hover у блоков на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, click, touch

Имееются повторяющиеся блоки следующего содержания:

```
<div class="advantage advantage-01">
  <div class="adv-wrapper">
    <div class="adv-img-cont">
    <img src="#" alt="Самые горящие">
   </div>
   <p class="descr-header"></p>
   <p class="hover-descr"></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Выглядят так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Смысл поведения в том что при ховере на элементе, невидимые абзацы становятся видимыми, а при анховере исчезают. С реализацией этого поведения проблем нет. Загвоздка в мобильной версии. На тач-устройствах ховер эмулируется событием тапа по экрану. Но чтобы убрать описание, приходится искать для тапа свободную область, которую трудно найти на маленьком экране. Как сделать чтобы при повторном клике на элемент происходил анховер. 
Пытался так:

```
$(function() {
    if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        $(".adv-wrapper", this).click(function(){
            $("p.hover-descr", this).toggle("fast");
        });
    }
    else {
        $(".adv-wrapper", this).hover(function () {
            $("p.hover-descr", this).toggle("fast");
        });
    }
});
```

Не завелось. Подскажите в чем подвох?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант.

Корректно работает даже при "live" ресайзе окна.

```js
$('.adv-wrapper').on('click', function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(this).find('p.hover-descr').toggle('fast');
  }
});
$('.adv-wrapper').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
    $(this).find('p.hover-descr').toggle('fast');
  }
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var tar = $('.adv-wrapper');
  if (!tar.is(e.target) && tar.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    tar.find('p.hover-descr').hide('fast', 'swing');
  }
});
```

```css
.adv-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: #f00 solid 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hover-descr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="advantage advantage-01">
  <div class="adv-wrapper">
    <div class="adv-img-cont">
    </div>
    <p class="descr-header">Заголовок</p>
    <p class="hover-descr">Описание</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант помог. Но вылезла другая неприятность. Теперь при клике за пределами блока текст не исчезает. Только если кликнуть на сам блок.

Comment: @Alex обновил ответ

Comment: @Alex если ответ помог, отметьте его, пожалуйста, его принятым, нажав на галочку

Answer (score 0):

как-то так:

```js
$(".advantage").click(function(){

    if($(window).width() < 767){
       $(this).toggleClass('mob-hov');
    }
    
});
```

```css
.advantage{padding:5px;width:100px;height:50px;border:1px solid;overflow:hidden}
.hover-descr{height:50px;position:;bottom:0}
@media screen and (min-width: 767px){
.advantage:hover{height:inherit}
}
.mob-hov{height:inherit!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="advantage advantage-01">
  <div class="adv-wrapper">
    <div class="adv-img-cont">
    <img src="#" alt="Самые горящие">
   </div>
   <p class="descr-header"></p>
   <p class="hover-descr">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
   </p>
 </div>
</div>
```